# Outside Click handle event on element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

can you tell me how can i handle a click on outside of element .For example i have that

```
<td><input type="number" className="hour" onKeyDown={this.editInlineHour(this)} /></td>
```

and i want only when i click outside of that element to execute some function and that is it in react !

I try it with that

```
  window.addEventListener('mousedown', this.pageClick, false);
```

but even when i click on input field the function is executed.Thanks
This is my full code ..basically it is inline edit on field on table.. when i click on that field it show input field.. and i want when i click outside that field do go away

```
editInlineHour:function () {

    },
    showInlineEditHour:function (i) {
        this.setState({
            index:i,
            showInlineHour:true
        })
    },
    showInlineEditStart:function (i) {
        this.setState({
            index:i,
            showInlineStart:true
        })
    },
    showInlineEditEnd:function (i) {
        this.setState({
            index:i,
            showInlineEnd:true
        })
    },
    pageClick:function () {
      this.setState({
          showInlineStart:false,
          showInlineEnd:false,
          showInlineHour:false
      });
    },
    render: function () {

        var itemMap = this.state.items.map(function (item, i) {
            var fieldDp1;
            if(this.state.showInlineStart){
                fieldDp1 = <input id="inlineDp1"  className="flatpickr" data-date-format="m/d/Y"/>
            }else{
                fieldDp1 = <td onDoubleClick={this.showInlineEditStart.bind(this,i)} ><FormattedDate value={item.startDate}/></td>
            }
            var fieldDp2;
            if(this.state.showInlineEnd){
                fieldDp2 = <input id="inlineDp2"  className="flatpickr" data-date-format="m/d/Y" />
            }else{
                fieldDp2 = <td onDoubleClick={this.showInlineEditEnd.bind(this,i)}><FormattedDate value={item.endDate}/></td>
            }
            var fieldHours;
            if(this.state.showInlineHour){
                fieldHours = <td><input type="number" className="hour" onKeyDown={this.editInlineHour(this)} /></td>
            }else{
                fieldHours =  <td  onDoubleClick={this.showInlineEditHour.bind(this,i)} >{item.workInHours}</td>

            }
            return (
                <tr key={i}>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" checked={item.selected} onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this,i)} /></td>
                    {fieldDp1}
                    {fieldDp2}
                    {fieldHours}
                    <td><label type="button" onClick={this.handleShowModal.bind(this,i)}><img height="30px" src="moliv.jpg"/></label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            );

        }.bind(this));
        return (
            <div>
                <button className="btn btn-primary center-block" onClick={this.addElem}>Add</button>
                {this.state.list.theList.length > 0 ?  <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.putResult}>Put result</button> :null}
                <table className="table scroll2">
                    <thead>
                    <tr className="danger">
                        <th><input  type="checkbox" checked={this.state.allChecked} onClick={this.toggleAll}/></th>
                        <th>Start Date</th>
                        <th>End Date</th>
                        <th>Hours</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {itemMap}

                    </tbody>

                </table>
                {this.state.items.length > 0 ? <button  type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.deleteItems}>Remove</button> : null}
                <Modal parentState={this.state} modalPropsId={this.props.theProps.id} handleHideModal={this.handleHideModal}/>
            </div>
        );
```

Comment: Could you provide your full code?

Comment: Ofc, I edit it and i wrote a little exactly what i want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add ref to your element and check if click event comes outside of it.

```
function handleClickOutside(evt) {
  if (this.refs.yourInput !== evt.target) {
    callSomeFunction();
  }
  return true;
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.clickHandler = handleClickOutside.bind(this);
  document.addEventListener('click', this.clickHandler, true);
} 

componentWillUnmount() {
  document.removeEventListener('click', this.clickHandler, true);
}
```

In case if you want to check outside click for some component with children, you can use `contains`

```
if (!this.refs.yourComponent.contains(evt.target)) {
  callSomeFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using that approach you will need to assign a `onClick` handler to your input element and stop propagation so that it doesn't propagate to the windows onClick event.

```
const handleInsideClick = (e) => {
   e.stopPropagation();
}
```

React handles events in a smart way, an event is triggered from the deeper node in the DOM to the top, so when you click in the input you can either stop propagation to the onClick handler in the parent node or do whatever you want in the click event and let it propagate.

Comment: Nahh,man it's not working if i assign a onClick event...still it's the same

Comment: @FreakProgrammer did you stopped propagation?

Comment: No, where i need to write this lines ?

Comment: @FreakProgrammer have you read my explanation about the way react handles events? Are you assigning the onClick event to the correct component and preventing the propagation?

Comment: @FreakProgrammer if you want to propagation to be stooped for the full table I would assign a function containing that logic I wrote in the top to <table> onClick event

Comment: @DiogoCunha I read it and it the same..i write e.stopPropagation() in onClick function and still the same..

Answer (score 0):

The event.preventDefault() method stops the default action of an element from happening if that what you're after.

```
 <td><input type="number" id="inputField" className="hour" onKeyDown={this.editInlineHour(this)} /></td>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#inputField").on("submit", function(event){
      event.preventDefault(); // Stop event 
      event.stopPropagation(); // Stop event (react)
});
```

http://jsbin.com/nejetoxeve/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap Component with a component with a `position: fixed` like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

const styles = (onClick) => ({
  position: 'fixed',
  pointerEvents: onClick ? 'auto' : 'none',
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  right: 0,
  left: 0,
  height: '100%',
});

export default class FixedLayer extends Component {

  static defaultProps = {
    zIndex: 2000,
    onClick: null,
  };

  render () {
    const divProps = { ...this.props };
    delete divProps.zIndex;
    return (
      <div { ...divProps }
        onClick={ (e) => this.props.onClick && (e.target === ReactDom.findDOMNode(this)) && this.props.onClick() }
        style={{...this.props.style, ...styles(this.props.onClick), ...{zIndex: this.props.zIndex}}}>
          {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```